# how to take decision based on a range of Integer values in bash script for example

Tags: bash

How to take decision based on an range of numerals in bash script?.
 For example ,I have list of filesystem with its utilization ,I need to take a specific action if the utilization is between 70%-80% and some second action of action if utilization is 80% to 90%  and third action if its above 90%I need to traverse through the entire list and take action for each filesystem based on its utilization..

I tried using elif statement but its not giving desired result.

how to take decision based on an range of numerals in bash script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean logic to do what you need:

```
$ size=75
$ [ 70 -le $size -a $size -le 80 ] && echo "70-80%"
70-80%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **case**:
[kinda Pseudocode]

```
case expression in
pattern1 )
    statements ;;
pattern2 )
    statements ;;
...
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Relace 'vol_name', with you Volume.

```
a=`df -h|grep vol_name|awk '{print $5}'|sed 's/%//'`

case "$a" in
9[1-9]|100)
    echo "almost full";;
8[1-9]|90)
    echo "need breather";;
..........
*)
    echo "some error"
esac
```

Comment: [root@ingura63 ~]# ./bashtesting.sh
Better hurry with that new disk...  One partition is 97 % full.
[root@ingura63 ~]#

Comment: #!/bin/bash

# This script does a very simple test for checking disk space.

space=`df -h | awk '{print $5}' | grep % | grep -v Use | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d "%" -f1 -`

case $space in
[1-6]*)
  echo "All is quiet."
  ;;
[7-8]*)
  echo "Start thinking about cleaning out some stuff.  There's a partition that is $space % full."
  ;;
9[0-8])
  echo "Better hurry with that new disk...  One partition is $space % full."
  ;;
99)
  echo "I'm drowning here!  There's a partition at $space %!"
  ;;
*)
  echo "I seem to be running with an nonexistent amount of disk space..."
  ;;
esac